# How to specify a fill character to string and split it by chunk?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am attempting to split a string of integers by every n character and then convert them to unicode. Unfortunately, I came across a problem... Since the leading 0s has been dropped from the string, it makes me confused about how to handle them. 
Here is an example：

```
print(num2txt(97097114103104))
```

Here the leading 97 is a valid number in the ASCII table and I can simple add a "0" before the string so that this whole string will be correctly split into something like this:

```
['097', '097', '114', '103', '104']
```

However, what if the first three digits are actually valid in the ASCII table? 
Like this:

```
100097114103
```

In this case I want it to be split into

```
['100', '097', '114']
```

But how do I make sure this does not need a "0" anymore if something happens in my function?

My current code is below:

```
def num2txt(num, k=3):

    line = str(num) 
    line = "0" + line
    line = [line[i:i+k] for i in range(0, len(line), k)]

    return line
```

Comment: To find out if you need to prepend a 0 you could check the result of len(str(line)) % 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add leading zeros when necessary.

```
def num2txt(num, k=3):

    line = str(num)
    padding = len(line)%k
    if padding:
        line = '0'*(k-padding) + line
    line = [line[i:i+k] for i in range(0, len(line), k)]

    return line
```

Comment: Yeah I was thinking why there were two '0' in that padding. But thank you for the prompt response. I finally got it!

Comment: One quick question... If I encouter something like this:     print(num2txt(65006600660065, k=4))  It would not properly split them. I want them to be thing s like 0065, 0066, 0065. But the code is giving me ['0650', '0660', '0660', '065']...Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry for bothering you. I got it. I suggest you might want to edit the padding to switch the place of '00' and '0' which will correctly output when k=4. Thank you!

Comment: @HarryLens - My apologies; I've fixed it for the general case (see edit).

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to something similar.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using [`math.ceil`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/math.html#math.ceil) to round up the length of my string to the multiple of `3` then [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) my string. From there to [split my string what other better way than using a generator function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)

```
import math
def num2txt(num, k):
    num_str = "{:0>{width}}".format(num, width=math.ceil(len(str(num))/k)*k)
    for n in range(0, len(num_str), k):
        yield num_str[n:n+k]
```

Demo:

```
>>> list(num2txt(97097114103104, 3))
['097', '097', '114', '103', '104']
```